# "Cannot read property `message` of null" while connecting to mongodb with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a walking skeleton for my MEAN app. I successfully connected to the mongodb (multivision db opened), but proceeding further I am getting the error described in the title while trying to print the message to the browser window:

[image: error message]

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/multivision');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error...'));
db.once('open', function callback() {
    console.log('multivision db opened');
});

var messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({message: String});
var Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
var mongoMessage= new Message({message: 'Hello mongoDB here'});
console.log(mongoMessage.message);
Message.findOne().exec(function(err, messageDoc) {
    mongoMessage = messageDoc.message;
})

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        mongoMessage: mongoMessage
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save `mongoMessage` before you can query for it:

```
mongoMessage.save(function(err, doc) {
    Message.findOne().exec(function(err, messageDoc) {
        mongoMessage = messageDoc.message;
    });
});
```